# Objective-C for loop failed

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, for-loop

I am new developer and have created a for loop. However, the 'for' loop value does not increment.

here is my code:

```
int j=0;
for (int i=0; i < localDocuments.count; i++) { 
    if(j<imageList.count){
        for (j=0; j<=i;j++) {
            NSURL * fileURL = [localDocuments objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@",[imageList objectAtIndex:j],PTK_EXTENSION];
            if ([[fileURL lastPathComponent] isEqualToString:str]){
                [self loadDocAtURL:fileURL];
            }//if
        }//for j
     }//if
}//for i
```

`i` does not increment when the `if ([[fileURL lastPathComponent] isEqualToString:str])` condition fails.

When the string values are not equal, the loop does not skip to the next file url.

Can anyone spot my mistake?

Comment: don't down vote i want solution if you know help me

Comment: Thank you @Anzeo for editing so it makes some sense.

Comment: `NSLog()` `[fileURL lastPathComponent]` and str

Comment: sorry guys my poor language skill please help me

Comment: @Popeye: I was the firstone to edit :p

Comment: i checked in NSLog() both are geting string

Comment: you have a nested loop, in j loop you will get as  i=0,j=0 then i=1, j=0,1 then i=2, j=0,1,2 etc...

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Yeah I know but Anzeo corrected his grammar and language so it was readable.

Comment: @VickyRaj: so do you want like this or what?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya no i want i=0,j=0,1,2,3,,, then i=1,j=0,1,2,3,,,, like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the nested loop (j), i will not increment. Also, you should consider resetting j to 0 (i don't really understand the `if(j<imageList.count)`condition.. should it be `imageList.count > 0` ?)

Answer (score 0):

As you said :

> no i want i=0,j=0,1,2,3,,, then i=1,j=0,1,2,3,,,, like that

You should use

```
for (j=0; j<localDocuments.count;j++) {
```

Comment: i have doubt please i want to load  selected image list which is in localdocument here what kind of statement we will use for loop or while loop

Comment: in one folder? Then simply use fast enumeration and use each element.

Comment: i don't know about fast enumeration concept please help me and give some useful reference